# Get multiple postgresql function returned cursors from Django

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new to django and not able to figure out if it is possible to retrieve multiple cursors returned by a postgresql function.

Edit: to return multiple cursors from postgresql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(parameters) RETURNS SETOF refcursor...
```

Further in the function body:

```
OPEN cursor1
- - some code to fill the cursor1
RETURN NEXT cursor1;

OPEN cursor2 
- - some code to fill the cursor2
RETURN NEXT cursor2;

RETURN;
```

I've been searching the net for hours now and haven't been able to find a single example.

I plan to write raw sql from django (no ORM) to call the postgresql functions.

Anyone to enlighten me?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show an example PostgreSQL function that returns multiple cursors, and what you've attempted with `psycopg2` so far?

Comment: Currently I have network issues with very limited bandwith and writting from my phone. Not easy to format code. I didn't try anything with psycog2 since I'm writting all my postgresql functions and tests first. Just wondering if I can use multiple cursors or not.

Comment: Just edited to give an example of how to return multiple cursors from postgresql function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentally, this seems to do the trick with bare psycopg2. The cursor provided by Django should be more or less compatible with a psycopg2 cursor:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

create_sql = """
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_cur() RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
DECLARE cursor1 refcursor;
DECLARE cursor2 refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor1 FOR SELECT x * x FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS x;
    RETURN NEXT cursor1;
    
    OPEN cursor2 FOR SELECT SQRT(x) FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS x;
    RETURN NEXT cursor2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
"""

with psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(create_sql)
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM multi_cur()")
        # Get the cursor names (['<unnamed portal 1>', '<unnamed portal 2>'])
        cursor_names = [r[0] for r in curs]
        # Fetch all results from those cursors
        for name in cursor_names:
            curs.execute(sql.SQL("FETCH ALL FROM {}").format(sql.Identifier(name)))
            print([r[0] for r in curs])
            for row in curs:
                print(row)
```

The output is

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903, 3.0, 3.1622776601683795]
```

quite as expected.

Comment: No you must not use `f` strings as there is the `psycopg2` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module available.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver please see the comment right above that line.

Comment: I saw it and it does not apply: `from psycopg2 import sql` and then `curs.execute(sql.SQL("FETCH ALL FROM {}").format(sql.Identifier(name)))`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, fair point, edited in. :) (Though I think f-strings would have been safe in _this particular limited case_ as I doubt Postgres would output "unsafe" cursor names.)

Comment: It is more about safe habits, not getting folks into using unsafe coding from the start. It takes out the decision of when should I do for A vs B and also the building of a potential security hole when the source of the values fed to a string change from trusted to untrusted and no one goes back to verify proper escaping is done.